# Uploading large attachments using Microsoft Graph API under the new throttling restrictions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

A [recent post](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/beta-outlook-api-throttling-limits-deploying-to-v1-0-on-microsoft-graph-may-2020/) in the Office 365 developer blog stated that there will be new upload limits enforced on the graph API and Outlook API:

> Each application is limited to uploading (POST, PUT, PATCH) 15
> megabits every 30 seconds per mailbox.

According to the new limit, if I want to upload a 10MB (80Mb) attachment via the API I need to split it to 15Mb chunks and wait 30 seconds between uploads. Under this limitation the operation will take 3 minutes to complete.

Graph API documentation specifies that this limit [applies to the attachment and message resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#outlook-service-limits). Graph beta version describes an [uploadSession resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=http) that can be used to upload large files.

Are the new upload throttling limits applied to the uploadSession resource?
Given the new limits, is there a timeline to move the uploadSession resource to GA?

Comment: [Same question](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/8443) was also posted in the graph documentation github page

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. After tracking the information down internally it appears that the limit is 15MB (bytes) not 15 Mb (bits) per 30 seconds. I authored a [pull request](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/8950) to correct the information.